# Advanced Search - No of results bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

[Question having score > 1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsublimetext%5D%20answers%3A0%20closed%3A0%20score%3A1)  178 Results (It should be below 178)

[Question having score > 0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsublimetext%5D%20answers%3A0%20closed%3A0%20score%3A0)  130 Results

How is it possible?

Comment: It’s *exactly* 0, not greater than or equal.

Comment: See "Advanced Search Tips": _"score:3 (3+) score:0 (none)"_

Comment: @CodeCaster But not mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The search parameter `score:0` is special in that it only matches posts with an exact score, unlike `score:<positive-or-negative-number>`, which match posts with a given score *and higher*.

The search results page does tell you that only score 0 is being matched:

> Search options not closed **score 0** answers 0

Compare that with your `score:1` search, which tells you a range is being matched:

> Search options not closed **score>= 1** answers 0

The “advanced search tips” in-line help also tells you it’s not going to match a range:

```
score:3 (3+)  
score:0 (none)
```

Use [`score:0..`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsublimetext%5D%20answers%3A0%20closed%3A0%20score%3A0..) if you need a range search, which gets you 308 results, neatly confirming that you got the same results of your two queries into one (178 + 130 = 308).

Comment: It should be mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: Perhaps, but that’s a separate issue.

Answer (score 5):

Because score:0 and score:1 do not have the same behavior.  You can see what the criteria each query is using by looking above the search bar.

[image: For your first link]
[image]

The difference is score:3 is returning all matching posts with a score of 1 or more whereas score:0 returns posts with a score of exactly 0.

The Advanced Search Tips on the search page define the behavior

[image]

To get posts scoring 0 or more you need to append a `..` after the zero.  This isn't in the advanced search tips I mentioned above, but is mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

`[sublimetext] answers:0 closed:0 score:0..` will return [what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsublimetext%5D%20answers%3A0%20closed%3A0%20score%3A0..)  (only 1 period will work actually, but the defined behavior is 2 periods)